# How to create thumbnails in R

Tags: r, thumbnails

I have a list of html files(plots) stored in my local directory. I want to make thumbnails of it. I am not sure how to do it in R.

It would be really helpful if anyone could advice/comment on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. If plots were generated in R, why not just save the plots as PNGs?

Comment: @MauritsEvers, I created the htmlwidgets of plots. Now I want to create thumbnail of those html files. And I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not following you. What are *"thumbnail of those html files"*? As I said, why not save the plots as PNGs and use those as thumbnail images?

Comment: @MauritsEvers, ok I can save the plots as PNG but when I am running this command `jpeg(file="C:/filename.html.jpg")`. I am getting an error do not support this file format while opening it.

Comment: *"ok I can save the plots as PNG"* But you're generating a JPG not a PNG. We need to see a [reproducible & minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Otherwise it'll be very difficult to provide any help.